Did Jamal Husseini say "The blood will flow like rivers in the Middle East"?
On page 50 of his 2008 book 1948: A History of the First Arab–Israeli War, Benny Morris wrote:

The Arab reaction was just as predictable: “The blood will flow like rivers in the Middle East,” promised Jamal Husseini.

There is a very similar quote by Heykal Pasha:

At the 29th Meeting of the UN Ad Hoc Committee on Palestine on 24 November 1947, Dr Heykal Pasha, the Egyptian delegate, said, "If the united Nations decideds to amputate a part of Palestine in order to establish a Jewish state,no force on earth could prevent blood from flowing there...However....once such bloodshed has commenced, no force on earth can confine it to the borders of Palestine itself. If Arab blood shed in Palestine, Jewish blood will necessarily be shed elsewhere in the Arab World despite all sincere efforts of the Governments concerned to prevent such reprisals. To place in certain and serious danger a million jews simply in order to save a hundred thousand in Europe or to satisfy the Zionist dream?
" source

Did the late Palestinian politician Jamal Al Husseini say that?

I see from Google Preview that the text has an end note (61) a couple of sentences later, but I can't read the end note. What does it say? Is it a reference by the author to support the claim?

if you mean the 61 one, it's "Beirut to FO, 17 September 1947, PRO FO 371-61529."  but I thought it referred to the conversation with Riad al-Sulh and the British diplomat since it came after that. I don't have access

Sounds reasonable. So the original author didn't reference it. Shame.

You can contact Benny Morris and ask him for the source of the quote.

he's way too famous
